# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, service, rpc

This exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): 
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
```

is received in my Windows Service when I run it on any machine, but when I test it in a test application no exception is thrown. In my code what I am doing is converting two .DAT files into .xls files. When I start the service through services.msc and run the service it runs fine for some time, but after updating certain rows it throws the exception and then  nothing happens after that. I have got  two separate functions that  does the work separately. The sample code is:

```
     public void SaveData_component(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            string filepath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["filepath"].ToString() + filename;
            filepath_first = filepath;

            object missing = Missing.Value;
            //string getExtension = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
            string getFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath) + "New";
            string filepathNew = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["filepath"].ToString() + getFilename + ".xls";

            try
            {
                xlAppNew1 = new Application();
                xlAppNew1.DisplayAlerts = true;
                workbooks1 = xlAppNew1.Workbooks;
                workbook1 = workbooks1.Open(@filepath, 0, true, 1, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                // xlWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                xlAppNew1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@filepathNew, -4143, "", "", false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);


                string getExtension = ".xls";//Path.GetExtension(filepathnew);
                //string getFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepathnew);
                string connString = "";

                if (getExtension.ToLower() == ".xls")
                    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepathNew + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

                else
                    connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepathNew + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;";

                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString);

                con.Open();
                System.Data.DataTable dtSheet = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string tname = dtSheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"Select * FROM [" + tname + "];", con);
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                ad.Fill(dset, "ProductOrderBOM");
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                System.Data.DataTable dttocopy = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt = dset.Tables["ProductOrderBOM"];
                if (dt != null || dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column5", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column6", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column7", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column8", typeof(string));
                    dttocopy.Columns.Add("Column9", typeof(string));

                    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dt.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                    {

                        dttocopy.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(3, 9), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(12, 4), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(16, 18), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(34, 8), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(42, 4), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(46, 18), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(64, 40), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(104, 3), dt.Rows[iRow][0].ToString().Substring(107, 5));

                    }

                    foreach (DataRow item in dttocopy.Rows)
                    {
                        if (item.ItemArray[0].ToString() != "" && item.ItemArray[5].ToString() != "" && item.ItemArray[8].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            string prdorderno = item.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim();
                            string materialcode = item.ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim();
                            double qty = Convert.ToDouble(item.ItemArray[8].ToString().Trim());

                            d1 = callprocedure(prdorderno, materialcode, Math.Round(qty, 2));
                            if (d1 != null)
                            {
                                if (d1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"] != null)
                                {
                                     WriteStuff(d1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                d1.Clear();
                d1.Dispose();
                dset.Clear();
                dset.Dispose();
                dtSheet.Clear();
                dtSheet.Dispose();
                dt.Clear();
                dt.Dispose();
                dttocopy.Clear();
                dttocopy.Dispose();
                ad.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                    WriteStuff(Convert.ToString(Ex) + "save_datacomponent function before finally");
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                if (workbooks1 != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks1);
                if (workbook1 != null)
                {
                    workbook1.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook1);
                }
                if (xlAppNew1 != null)
                {
                    xlAppNew1.Quit();
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlAppNew1);
                }


            }
```

This  is the function where the work is done.Any help would be greatly appreciable.
My Writestuff() Method is catching the following Exception:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.Close(Object SaveChanges, Object Filename, Object RouteWorkbook)at MyNewService.MyNewService.SaveData_component(String filename)savedata_component functionSystem.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\SUMIT\COMPONENT_TAI_PT1_RMKH_3799_20130603_030504New_03-06-2013-18-07-09-537_04-06-2013-16-42-20-194.DAT'.
```

Also if I get rid of the clear methods in my code and the

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject();
```

Another exception comes in my way:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.Close(Object SaveChanges, Object Filename, Object RouteWorkbook)at MyNewService.MyNewService.SaveData_component(String filename)
```

I am really not sure what  the hell is hapenning.

Comment: The line that begins `dttocopy.Rows.Add(...` is suspect because it presumes that the length of the string it finds is always >= 4 (it uses 3 index in `SubString()`).  What if that is not true?  You get an exception.  You should first test `dt.Rows[iRow][0]` string length before proceeding with `SubString()` operations.

Comment: Are you catching exceptions?  Is your `WriteStuff()` method grabbing useful information?

Comment: Sigh, these questions never end.  Easy enough to diagnose the problem, all you need is Task Manager.  You'll see the dozens of instances of Excel.exe that your code doesn't actually managed to release.  Get rid of your global "xl" variables and make them local variables.  Get rid of all these ineffective Clear() and ReleaseComObject() calls.  Test your code to ensure that Excel.exe stops running after the GC.Collect + WaitForPendingFinalizers calls.  Do *not* test your Debug build, only the Release build without a debugger attached.

Comment: Ok I got it, my Task Manager did had dozens of unclosed EXEL.EXE opened. I will give you the Error that my Writestuff() method is catching. I am not having any clue as to where I am going wrong.I have closed every instance of COM objects that I have created. Can you please tell me if I have done something wrong in releasing the COM objects.

Comment: How can I get rid of the Excel.exe that are being generated. I did as told by you but still one Excel.exe by system remains and the same error persists.

Comment: This [(COM Interop, RPC server is unavailable in c#)][1] might answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588201/com-interop-rpc-server-is-unavailable-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

While the article states that Office 2003 support has ended, the contents are still valid today: Microsoft does not support server-side automation of Office. Even in client-side automation Office interop is pretty quirky.

You're best off with a library such as Aspose or NPOI.